# String date format is not working for two different month

Tags: android

i am comparing two string dates then it's working for same month and return record from sqlite database but for different month it's not working and return o record.I mean it's not working for two different month. Please suggest me what i do.

date format is "25 sep 2013"
it's return record for sep but not for oct  or other different months.

Thanks

my java code is

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
SimpleDateFormat    dfDate_day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
Date resultdate = new Date(cal.getTimeInMillis());
String maxdate = dfDate_day.format(resultdate);
Cursor c4 = db_category.selecttaskdate1(maxdate);
count = c4.getCount();
c4.close();
```

my database code is

```
public Cursor selecttaskdate1(String maxdate)

{
SQLiteDatabase db12= this.getReadableDatabase();

String[] columns = { main_Tasknewid, main_Taskname, main_Taskid, Task_Catid,    main_Taskdate, main_TaskCreatorUrl, main_Taskcreatorname, main_Taskreadunread,  main_Taskregno, main_Taskattachment, main_Taskattachmentname,  Email_id,star_status,Checked_status };

Cursor c = db12.query(main_Task, columns,
main_Taskdate+"<=?",new String[]{maxdate}, null, null, null);



if ((c.getCount() == 0) || !c.moveToFirst()) {
//throw new SQLException("No items found");
}       
return c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way may help

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

        cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
        SimpleDateFormat    dfDate_day = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");
        String maxdate = dfDate_day.format(cal.getTime()); // UPDATE HERE
        Cursor c4 = db_category.selecttaskdate1(maxdate);
        count = c4.getCount();
        c4.close();
```

Comment: get count 0 when month is deffrent

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at your DB code, and i noticed you're querying all the rows whose date are smaller than the supplied "max date". Not sure if the september / october example you gave is real, but if it is, october dates shouldn't return anyway, since october is after september.

In anycase, I would suggest adjusting the comparison in the db code to something like this:

```
Cursor c = db12.query(main_Task, columns, main_Taskdate+"<=date(?)",new String[]{maxdate}, null, null, null);
```

Notice the date() parsing there. 
That should hopefully solve the problem.

Hope this helps :)